# Simple stats question A level help

Tags: probability

I've not done stats in a while and struggling with simple questions like these. Can anyone help?

The probability that Adam will pass the hard examination is 0.12. The probability that Brian will pass it is 0.19. The probability that they will both pass is .05.

1. Find the probability that at least one of the two will pass.
2. Find the probability that both fail.

Comment: Have you studied Venn diagrams. You can start there to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If P(both pass) = 0.05, then probability both fail is 1 -0.05 -0.12 -0.19 = 0.64.

Comment: Can anybody confirm if I am correct?